# What is the story of Nara and Narayana's brothers Hari and Krishna?

Tags: vishnu, mahabharata, avatars, pancharatra

As I discuss in [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3712/36), one of the most prominent incarnations of Vishnu in ancient times was the sage Narayana, twin brother of the sage Nara and son of Yama god of death.  Nara and Narayana were famous for engaging in Tapasya (deep meditation) in Badrikashrama, and in the time of the Mahabharata they were reborn as Arjuna and Krishna.  In any case, apparently Narayana carried out a five-night (Pancharatra) Yagna and then became the entire universe, so people started following the so-called Pancharatra texts, scriptures originating from Narayana himself which gave detailed procedures for worshipping him.  As I discuss in [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3843/36), the Pancharatra texts were important in the development of Vaishnavism.  Among the oldest Pancharatra texts are the Satvata Samhita, the Paushkara Samhita, and the Jayakhya Samhita.

But there's a Pancharatra text even older than these, and it is found within the Mahabharata!  Most people only know about the Bhagavad Gita, an 18-chapter religious discourse between Krishna and Arjuna found in the beginning of the Bhishma Parva of the Mahabharata.  But there is another 18-chapter religious discourse found at the end of the Shanti Parva of the Mahabharata, the Narayaniya.  It is a Pancharatra text which takes the form of a dialogue between Yudhishtira and Bhishma as the latter is lying on the battlefield of Kurukshetra, and Yudhishtira asks him questions about the importance of worshipping Narayana/Vishnu.  (It goes from [this chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12c034.htm) to [this chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12c051.htm) in the Shanti Parva; apparently the Bhagavad Gita and the Narayaniya divide the Mahabharata into three equal parts.)

In any case, in the [first chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12c034.htm) of the Narayaniya, Bhishma describes the birth of the sages Nara and Narayana:

> I heard it from my sire that in the Krita age, O monarch, during the epoch of the Self-born Manu, the eternal Narayana, the Soul of the universe, took birth as the son of Dharma in a quadruple form, viz., as **Nara, Narayana, Hari, and the Self-create Krishna**. Amongst them all, Narayana and Nara underwent the severest austerities by repairing to the Himalayan retreat known by the name of Vadari, by riding on their golden cars.

My question is, what is the story of Nara and Narayana's brothers Hari and Krishna?  The only other information the Narayaniya provides about them is Narada's statement that Hari and Krishna lived in Badrikashrama before Nara and Narayana:

> That form took birth in four shapes for the expansion of the race of Dharma which have been reared by that deity. How wonderful it is that Dharma has thus been honoured by these four great deities viz., Nara, Narayana, and Hari and Krishna! In this spot Krishna and Hari dwelt formerly. The other two, however, viz., Nara and Narayana, are now dwelling here engaged in penances for the object of enhancing their merit.

The only other scriptural reference I could find to Hari and Krishna is in [this excerpt](http://gdurl.com/cQ-9) from the Vamana Purana:

> The divine body Dharma born from the heart of Brahma, had reproduced Hari, Krishna, Nara and Narayana sons by virtue of consummating with his wife Dakshayani.... Hari and Krishna engrossed themselves with exercise on Yoga.  Nara and Narayana the greatest among all ancient sages began austerity with Parabrahma at the ever broad bank of the sacred Ganges in Badrikashrama, a place situated in the great Himalaya.

So first of all, how did Hari and Krishna's practicing of Yoga differ from their brothers Nara and Narayana's practicing of Tapasya?  Second of all, what caused Hari and Krishna to leave Badrikashrama?  Did they die or something?  And in any case, what was Vishnu's purpose in incarnating as Hari and Krishna?

Are there any other Hindu scriptures which mention these two brothers?  Note that this Hari is different from Vishnu's incarnation Hari who rescued Gajendra, whom I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/6608/36).

Comment: +1.. You are sharp analyzer Keshav... you are seriously very curious and I bet this question will be unanswered for a long time, because this is very high quality and high level question.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi Thanks!  Yeah, I am really curious; I actually have a long list of questions I want to ask, which keeps getting bigger, and every so often I take one of the questions on the list and post it on the site.  I can show you the list in chat if you want.  By the way, if you're interested in the topic of this question, there are a few other questions I've posted about Vishnu's incarnation Narayana, http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3712/36 and http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3843/36 in particular.

Comment: I am not sure, but in my childhood, I have listened story from one saint, in that story he was mentioning that Nar-Narayan went to Bandrikashrm, and Hari went to Vaikuntha and Krishna went to Golok. and then topic changed or maybe I don't remeber. I don't know which scripture he was referring to.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan have you read all this scriptures... its really great man (Y)

Comment: only people I had im my mind who study these scripture deeply was saint. thanks for breaking that thought,

Comment: It is interesting, because the Vamana Purana makes a passing reference to them in its sixth chapter 1st verse, like, "Dharma had four sons, Hari, Krsna, Nara and Narayana. Then Hari and Krsna concentrated on Yoga."
That's it. Then they just disappear.
EDIT: Which I find you have already posted... Sheesh.

Comment: @Surya Yeah, so I think there's a real possibility that they just performed Yoga and died.  That would explain why Hari and Krishna were no longer in Badri when Nara and Narayana were engaging in Tapasya.

Comment: You know, in the Bhagavatam, when Muchukunda retires to Badarikashrama, it is given: Tapasa Aradhayat **Harim**. (He worshipped **Hari**. So it's like, he just met Krsna, he is at the ashrama of Nara-Narayana, and now he worships the fourth brother, Hari.

Comment: There is also the possibility that Hari and Krsna merged into Nara Narayana, because in the fourth Canto, 1st Chapter, 59th Verse, they are described as **Hareh Amsau**, the expansions of Hari.

Comment: It's a clever thought, but I think Hari is just being used as a name of Vishnu, especially considering that in the previous chapter Muchukunda addresses Krishna as Hari.  And I think the Hareh Amsau thing is definitely using Hari as a name of Vishnu.  Besides, I don't know of any story where one incarnation of Vishnu merges into another incarnation.

Comment: @Surya By the way, there's another incarnation of Vishnu named Hari whom I discuss here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/6608/36

Comment: I have a theory that each word in Bhagavatam is used for a specific purpose, like Shukabrahmarshi never throws the words off just as names, like for referring Vishnu, if he says Narayana it means something, and if he says Hari, then it means something else. Like that.

Comment: I know that Hari too... but obviously HE is not referred here. :)

Comment: @Surya Well, first of all Shuka isn't the author, Vyasa is.  Second of all, if you go through the Srimad Bhagavatam, I expect you won't find any discernible pattern in what name of Vishnu Vyasa uses when.  Certainly Vyasa uses some names with greater frequency than other names, but that's about all you can say.  Also, I'm pretty sure the phrase "hareh-amsau" or close synonyms occur elsewhere in the Srimad Bhagavatam in contexts having nothing to do with Nara and Narayana.

Comment: @Surya Just look at all these instance of the word "hareh" and see if you can discern a pattern: http://www.vedabase.com/en/synonyms-index?original_op=contains&original=Hareh&translation_op=contains&translation= I think Vyasa is just praising Vishnu with different names to convey Vishnu's greatness.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31106/discussion-between-surya-and-keshav-srinivasan).

Comment: You know, one of the meanings of Hari is the alleviator of suffering. And in most of the verses, this meaning fits with the context.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan srila Rupa Goswami in LaghuBhagavatamrit says that actually Nara-Narayand and Hari-krishna are the same person(He says one incarnation). Hari and Krishna is other name used by some scriptures fro Nara and Narayana.

Comment: @Vishalprabhulawande Well, the Shanti Parva of the Mahabharata specifically says "In this spot Krishna and Hari dwelt formerly. The other two, however, viz., Nara and Narayana, are now dwelling here engaged in penances for the object of enhancing their merit."  So the two pairs of brothers dwelt in Badrikashrama at separate times.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan - There is one verse in shreemad Bhagvat purana ( 2 skandha  chapter 7 verse 2) ,which is about how Shree Vishnu got his name "Hari" , It States - "Further prabhu took avatar in the form of "Suyagna" to "Akuti" from "Ruchi" prajapati. In this avatara he created "Suyam" deities from.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar By the way, I posted a question about Yagna's father Ruchi here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3664/36

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan -... Wife named "Dakshina".He then rescued 3 lokas , and then Swayambhuva manu given him the name "Hari".but that is not saying anything abt krishna.Is your question about that Hari or something different.

Comment: @Swiftpushkar No, my question isn't about Vishnu's incarnation Yagna son of Ruchi.  My question is about Vishnu's incarnations Hari and Krishna who are brothers of Nara and Narayana.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan - Oh ok :)

Answer (score 4):

The Satsangijeevan (Ahmedabad edition) has vast chapters dedicated to this detail where Dharma (father of Nar Narayan) explains to Rishi Sanak the advent of Lord Nara Narayana.

Satsangijeevan (Adhyay 4 Chapter 31)
"....The first Swarup of benevolent and merciful
Lord will become known as Bhagwan Narayan, as He will redeem and grant salvation
to innumerable souls that are lost in the never ending cycle of death and rebirth due to
their ignorance or past deeds. He will also be known as Lord Narayan as human race
can attain Moksha only through Him. He will also be known as Lord Narayan as He
rests on a bed made of the coiled serpent Shesh in the middle of an ocean at the end
of Atyantik Pralay. As He is the sole controller of uncountable universes, Maya and
Kaal, His second Swarup will be known as Bhagwan Nar. In the absence of all feminine
features such as a raised chest (or breasts) and long hair, He will be known as Lord
Nar (the complete male). Bhagwan Nar and Narayan will proceed to Badrikaashram
to undergo severe austerity together for the benevolence of people of Bharat Khand
 He will also be known as Lord Nar as He, through His potency, will guide the
great kings on the path of righteousness.

The third Swarup of Bhagwan will be known
as Lord Hari as He will remove all sorrows of the Devtas and anyone coming under
His shelter.

The fourth Swarup will become known as Bhagwan Krishna as He will
attract and merge within Him the brilliant radiance that has mesmerised and bewildered
the Devtas and demons. O Muni! The other Devtas and I prepared for the worship of the four Swarups of Bhagwan after Brahma completed their introduction and naming..."

Satsagijeevan (Adhyay 4 Chapter 39)
Dharmadev said, “O Sanak Muni! Our illusion and ignorance vanished after
hearing Narayan Bhagwan’s sermon. Narayan Bhagwan asked Bhagwan Nar, Hari
and Krishna to let the female deities worship them. Listening immediately to Lord
Narayan, Bhagwan Nar said, ‘Hold on! Nar and Narayan cannot be separated. Nar
always follow Narayan. Whatever Narayan does, Nar emulates.’ 
Just as Bhagwan
Hari and Krishna were about to stop female deities offering their worship, Bhagwan
Narayan asked them to relent. Understanding the latent desire of Bhagwan Narayan,
Lord Hari and Krishna permitted deities to worship them. The female deities, aware of
Lord Narayan’s wish, happily performed elaborate worship of Lord Hari and Krishna with camphor, Kumkum, sandalwood paste etc. They offered many expensive golden
robes, ornaments such as bracelets and earrings and many flower garlands..."

Satsangijeevan (Adhyay 4 Chapter 40)
 Dharmadev said, “O Sanak Muni! Bhagwan Narayan got up to leave after soothing
my mind with His divine sermon. He asked Brahma, Vishnu, Shiva and other Devtas
to return to their respective abodes. 
He stopped Bhagwan Hari and Krishna from
accompanying Him and for the benevolence of mankind, advised them individually.

‘O
Hari! Please proceed to Vainkunth with Laxmiji. O Krishna! Please go and make Your
home at Golok. O Vaasudev! Please proceed to Shwetdweep and O Sankarshan!
You proceed to the bottom of earth to hold it steady. O Pradhyumna! Protect and
sustain the whole universe by residing on Lokalok Mountain. O Aniruddha! Dwell as a
soul of Virat and help in the process of creation.’ O Muni! Bhagwan Nar and Narayan,
dressed as Naisthik Brahamcharis and ever eager to undergo severe austerities,
departed for Badrikaashram after assigning the various benevolent tasks.

We were
very depressed, but nonetheless, sprinkled flowers as a good portent on the path
Bhagwan Nar and Narayan walked. Their radiant and round faces had a serene smile;
their eyes were large and beautiful like petals of a lotus, their hands were long enough
to reach their knees; their teeth were uniformly set and sparkling white, their large
chest were adorned with the insignia of ‘Shree Vatsa’; their wide foreheads and beautiful
ears lent their faces an extra splendour and their bodies emanated luminous radiance
like the sun or moon. Holding Kamandalus in their hands, Bhagwan Nar and Narayan
walked together, flanked by many people eager for their Darshan. I, other Devtas,
Gandharva and sages led by Narad walked behind Him to bid Him farewell. Bhagwan
Narayan stopped us after a while and asked us to turn back. He went to Badrikaashram
and lived under a berry tree called ‘Vishala’ where Bhagwan Nar has remained in His
service ever since. As others returned to their respective homes and hermits, I came
here.”