# Did sage Nara and Narayan still live even in 28th Dwapar Yuga?

Tags: vishnu, avatars, bhagavata-purana, yuga

Nara and Narayan were the incarnation of Lord Vishnu. Who later incarnated in last Dwapara as Arjuna and Krishna.

Nara-Narayan incarnation has been discussed in [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3936/what-is-the-story-of-nara-and-narayanas-brothers-hari-and-krishna).

[In 9th Canto Chapter 3](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/9/3/chapter-view) of Bhagavata purana

This is what lord Brahma tells Kakudmi when he arrives in Brahma Loka with his daughter Revati.

> Twenty-seven catur-yugas have already passed. Those upon whom you may
> have decided are now gone, and so are their sons, grandsons and other
> descendants. You cannot even hear about their names.
>
> O King, leave here and offer your daughter to Lord Baladeva, who is
> still present. He is most powerful. Indeed, He is the Supreme
> Personality of Godhead, whose plenary portion is Lord Viṣṇu. Your
> daughter is fit to be given to Him in charity.

I assume here Baladeva refers to Lord Balaram; Brother of Lord Krishna. So we know that this story is from last Dwapara yuga if I'm not mistaken.

And then Kakudmi after marrying his daughter to Lord Balaram goes to Badarikashram.

> Thereafter, the King gave his most beautiful daughter in charity to
> the supremely powerful Baladeva and then retired from worldly life and
> went to Badarikāśrama to please Nara-Nārāyaṇa.

So my question is: **were sages Nara-Nārāyaṇa still present at that time in BadarikaShram?**

**Or is it that Kakudmi went to Badarika to please them by worshipping them(not personally in case they had already departed for their abode)?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, Sage Nara and Narayan still lived at least uptill the beginning of 28th Kali Yuga in BadrikAshram.**

In [3rd canto of Bhagavatam](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/3/4) when Vidura was having a dialog with Uddhav. Uddhava being deeply saddened by separation from Lord Krishna(after Lord's disappearance); This is what Uddhav says:

> My dear Vidura, now I am mad for want of the pleasure of seeing Him,
>   and just to mitigate this I am now proceeding to Badarikāśrama in the
>   Himālayas for association, as I have been instructed by Him.
>
> There in Badarikāśrama the Personality of Godhead, in His incarnation
>   as the sages Nara and Nārāyaṇa, has been undergoing great penance
>   since time immemorial for the welfare of all amiable living entities.

So Nara and Narayan sages still lived in Badrikashram even in the beginning of Kali Yuga.

Comment: If nara and narayana still lived in 28th dwapar yuga then why does Lord shiva say to arjuna that "Thou wert in thy former life Nara, the friend of Narayana. " which can be found in mahabharata here https://sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03040.htm

Mahadeva specifically says "in your former life" which means arjuna's sukshma sharira was inside the body which was called nara before , or could it be that nara and narayana were still alive at that point but some portion of nara became arjuna ?