# How many days are there in one Yuga?

Tags: yuga, time

How many days are there in one Yuga (each of the four Yugas)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're interested in the number of days as opposed to the number of years, but in any case it's simple arithmetic.  [Here](http://sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp037.htm) is how the Vishnu Purana describes the lengths of the four Yugas:

> They are thus distributed: the Krita age has four thousand divine years; the Tretá three thousand; the Dwápara two thousand; and the Kali age one thousand: so those acquainted with antiquity have declared.

Now we need to convert divine years into human years, and then human years into human days.  Thankfully the Vishnu Purana gives us the relevant information [immediately before](http://sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp037.htm) the quote above:

> Thirty Muhúrttas constitute a day and night of mortals: thirty such days make a month, divided into two half-months: six months form an Ayana (the period of the sun's progress north or south of the ecliptic): and two Ayanas compose a year.  The southern Ayana is a night, and the northern a day of the gods. Twelve thousand divine years, each composed of (three hundred and sixty) such days, constitute the period of the four Yugas, or ages.

So a year of the gods is 360 days of the gods, and a day of the gods is 1 human year.  So we need multiply the above figures by 360 to get the length of the Yugas in human years: the Satya Yuga is 1,440,000 years, the Treta Yuga is 1,080,000 years, the Dwapara Yuga is 720,000 years, and the Kali Yuga is 360,000 years.  If we factor in the the Sandhya and Sandhyansa periods that come before and after each Yuga, we get that the Satya Yuga is 1,728,000 years, the Treta Yuga is 1,296,000 years, the Dwapara Yuga is 864,000 years, and the Kali Yuga is 432,000 years.

Now a human year is said to be two Ayanas, which works out to 360 days.  So if we convert the above figures to days, we get that, **the Satya Yuga is 622,080,000 days, the Treta Yuga is 466,560,000 days, the Dwapara Yuga is 311,040,000 days, and the Kali Yuga is 155,520,000 days**.  Whew!

Comment: @Pritam You're welcome.  By the way, why exactly were you interested in the number of days?

Comment: I was reading [this](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2875/what-exactly-happens-at-end-of-kali-yuga-how-will-the-world-be-destroyed). In your answer and comments, this question was raised. @Keshav Srinivasan.

Comment: @Keshav Srinivasan that might be correct because as yuketashwar giri has something with superstar of sun there might be even bigger entity which we(our sun and solar system) run around and that is what causing the yuga cycle. so with such massive entity it makes vast changes in yuga cycles

Comment: @Creator Well, I don't think the Yugas have anything to do with the motion of the Sun; as far as I know Hindu scripture never discusses the Yugas being caused by some astronomical phenomenon. The Yugas are just cycles created by the gods which affect spiritual and moral character of human beings and the like; they don't reflect changes in the Universe the way Kalpas do.  (But changes in Yugas are still marked in the stars; when the Kali Yuga began the Navagraha went into alignment.) By the way, Yukteswar doesn't even believe in Manvantaras and Kalpas, so his view of things is very different.

Comment: how does kalpa mark changes in universe?? death of bramha what else.

Comment: @Creator Actually Brahma only dies at the end of the Mahakalpa; he just goes to sleep at the end of the Kalpa.  In any case, at the end of the Kalpa the Universe is destroyed; see my answer here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2876/36

Comment: Some place in internet, I found that Satyayuga is around 12k years and others so on in decreasing order, that seems sensible. In your answer, there is no accounting of Jurassic age and evolution of humankind. Directly opposed to modern science. I think Gods Year = N x Human year, where N should be somewhere in 1 to 10.

Comment: And this forms one chaturyug. There are 71 such chaturyugas in one Manvantar. 14 such Manvantars form 1 day of Brahma. 360 Brahma days = 1 Brahma year and there are 100 such brahma years.
Currently we are in 51st Brahma year, 1st day, 7th Manvantar, 28th Kaliyuga's 5117th year. :)

Comment: Is this is coincidence that I am getting 9 when I sum all digits?

Comment: @Parikshitha It's a simple mathematical fact.  Any number which is divisible by 9 yields 9 if you sum up all the digits.  Since the numbers here are all divisible by 360, they are also divisible by 9.

Comment: Not only that, sum the digits of all yugas. You will get nine.

Comment: @Parikshitha Yeah, because the sum of numbers divisible by 9 is a number divisible by 9.

Comment: That I know. As the sum of numbers is 9, the yuga Theory may be symbolic rather than literal. That's what I mean.

Comment: @Parikshitha Like I said, the only reason the sums of digits of these numbers add to 9 is that they're divisible by 9, the only reason they're divisible by 9 is that they're divisible by 360, and they only reason they're divisible by 360 is that there are 360 days in the year.  So it has nothing to do with being symbolic, it just has to do with the numbers of days in a year.  In any case, I think the Yuga theory is definitely literal and not symbolic.

Answer (score 5):

The number of years varies in the four yugas as below:

> The duration of the Satya millennium equals 4,800 years of the years of the demigods; the duration of the Dvapara millennium equals 2,400 years; and that of the Kali millennium is 1,200 years of the demigods. [SB - 3.11.19]

And calculating those god years in human years (1 god year = 360 human years) and similarly taking one year roughly to be 360 days would have the following values:

Satya Yuga   - (1,728,000 solar years) - 622,080,000 days
Treta Yuga   - (1,296,000 solar years) - 466,560,000 days
Dvapara Yuga - (864,000 solar years) - 311,040,000 days
Kali Yuga    - (432,000 solar years)     - 155,520,000 days

More Reference:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu_units_of_time