# Yugas and Dinosaurs

Tags: yuga, brahma

I have heard about the 4 Yugas, the Mahayuga and how Brahma created everything and how many human years is equivalent to Brahma's 1 single day.

But to which Yuga did the Dinosaurs belong to?

Comment: yugas are very short span (considering the oldest known dinosaur was 65 million years ago according to Wiki). they repeat for each chatur yuga, which repeat for each manvantara. Manvantara repeats for each kalpa. so the answer you would be looking for could (if at all) be any yuga, but in a previous chaturyuga or manvantara . all the best.

Comment: @Sai We're living in the 28th Kali Yuga of the Vaivasvata Manvantara, so 65 million years ago (which is when dinosaurs went extinct) would have been in the same Manvantara but another Mahayuga.  (I'm using the numbers from my answer [here](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/5253/36).)

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan well not everyone agrees on those numbers therefore I left the possibility open that it may be from another Manvantara. Whatever it is, it is definitely not in the same yuga and in the same mahayuga :). Thanks for the info

Comment: @Sai I think the only people who disagree with these numbers are Yukteswar and his followers; he thought that there's no difference between god years and human years, and that the Kali Yuga got over a long time ago and that we're currently in the Dwapara Yuga.  And he didn't believe that Manvantaras and Kalpas even exist!  So in his system he wouldn't say that it happened in a previous Manvantara either.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan yes considering that Sri Yuktweshwar says in Holy Science that He received that knowledge from His Guru's Guru Mahavatar Babaji that would cover a big list of monks and ascetics who come under the Guru parampara. Swami Vivekananda also when asked about the Yugas said (according to http://www.ramakrishnavivekananda.info/vivekananda/volume_5/questions_and_answers/selections_from_the_math_diary.htm) that " There is no mention of such divisions (ofYugas) in the Vedas. They are arbitrary assumptions of Pauranika times". Also some modern saints have said Kali Yuga is to end soon :)

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan You're right about 'in his system he wouldn't say that it happened in a previous Manvantara either'. But there are many other saints whom I have seen to give various other interpretations of the Yuga system. Therefore atleast for me, there is no clear view on this. Either way this discussions is a better fit for http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2220/what-is-the-duration-timeline-of-the-four-yugas?rq=1 :) all the best

Comment: Guys, I was just talking about Yugas and Dinosaurs... Why is the topic going so tangential? I am not sure what are these discussions about Sri Yuktweshwar? Please try and answer just my question which is in which Yuga were there Dinosaurs? Which MahaYuga/Chaturyuga of the current Manvantara?

Comment: @user3750229 sorry we tend to do that a lot :)

Comment: one thing I want to know as well, are there any discussion or description about dinosaurs in our vedas or puranas??

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I have got birth year of Sri Rama which perfectly fits in the Treta Yuga of Sri Yukteswar's Yuga theory. Ramayan confirms his birth and that birth year validates Sri Yukteswar's theory. Now I have no doubt that his yuga theory is 100% right.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Can you give me the details?  Astronomical positions recur fairly regularly, especially considering that Hindu scripture doesn't give exact degree measurements for angles, only which of the 27 Nakshatras the moon is in.  And Samvatsara names recur every 60 years.  By the way, do you believe in Manvantaras and Kalpas?  Because Adi Shankaracharya did, as described in his Brahma Sutra Bhashya. So if you believe in Yukteswar's theory, you're rejecting the views of Adi Shankaracharya.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Using planetary information from Ramayana, Sri Rama's birth date was calculated to be January 10, 5114 BC. Taking present year(2015), 7128 years have passed since his birth. Taking the Treta Yuga period from my answer [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9009/did-ramayana-occur-1-6-million-years-ago/9015#9015), 7128 years perfectly fit in that period.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Like I said, the planetary positions used to get 5114 BC frequently recur, so that doesn't prove much.  I expect that they even recur multiple times in the Yukteswar-defined Treta Yuga.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan This research was done using some advanced softwares procured from US. If it happened many times, they could have have given the year of 1000 BC or 2000 BC, or 10000 BC but why they gave the date of just 5114 BC? Anyways, further calculations showed that Hanuman met Sita in Ashok Vatika in 5067 BC.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan All the researches are fitting perfectly in Sri Yukteswar's theory and that too in Treta Yuga only. If it were wrong, it could have gone in Dwapar Yuga or Kali Yuga or any other yuga.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria I have no doubt that if we take the million-year Yuga lengths, we'll find one or more dates that correspond to the 24th Treta Yuga matching all the astronomical information.  The standard Puranic Yuga lengths are long enough that there would be plenty of time to recur.  In any case, I think what the people who calculated the 5114 BC date is they took the most recent date that worked.  I doubt they said that that was the only date that worked in all history, but I'd have to examine their work.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria According to paramahamsa yogananda,desciple of Yukteshwar, who clearly stated that yukteshwar is talking about another ecquinoctial cycle occurring within current kaliyuga. So he is talking about ascending dwapara within current kaliyuga.It is mentioned in the footnote of "Autobiography of yogi".

Comment: Here is his precise quote "The Hindu scriptures place the present world-age as occurring within the Kali Yuga of a much longer universal cycle than the simple 24,000 year ecquinoctial cycle with which Sri Yukteswar was concerned. The universal cycle of the scriptures of 4,300,560,000 years in extent, and measures out a Day of Creation. "

Comment: Hindu Scriptures clearly say that First 10000 years of present kaliyuga is golden years , But dont mention years within .They talk about every Main yuga and Yuga Sandhi , but dont talk about cycles within that.

Comment: @sysinit Paramahamsa Yogananda is not talking about yugas in yugas, those sentences don't mean that he is saying we are in dwapara in Kali Yuga. What he said is that the present age is NO kali yuga at all. Kali Yuga has already ended.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria if Kali Yuga ended, why didn't Kalki arrive?

Comment: @AnilKumar Not sure about Kalki but Lord Shiva did appear at the end of Kali Yuga in the form of Chhatrapati Shivaji. He was born around 1630 and died in 1680. According to Sri Yukteswar, Kali Yuga ended in 1699.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria But scriptures say Vishnu would come as Kalki. Also, Chatrapathi Shivaji didn't completely remove invaders from Indian Subcontinent.

Comment: @AnilKumar Nothing is ever completely removed. Did Krishna remove each and every evil from whole planet? No, he didn't. By the way if you are interested in Sri Yukteswar's yuga theory, I have posted [an answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2220/what-is-the-duration-timeline-of-the-four-yugas/9965#9965) on the same.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria I agree with you. But for now i don't believe in Yukteswara's theory. But i started believing Mahavir Babaji as avatar of Lord Shiva. It was clearly stated in many puranas that Satya Yuga Tcomes after Kali Yuga and it was explained clearly **how too much of one Guna leads to its complementary Guna**. This is law of nature. For eg, when evil reaches pinnacle virtue sprouts from it. See [this answer](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/9205/3500). The same was explained in Linga Purana which made by stand stronger to conventional theory of Yugas.

Comment: @AnilKumar That's why Sri Yukteswar wrote the book - to give arguments against why the wrong theory came in puranas. He even mentioned it happened due to scholars like Kulluka Bhatta in the kingdom of Hastinapura after the Pandavas left. You have also mentioned sandhi periods in between yugas. That is also the case for Sri Yukteswar's theory. For ex - When ascending Dwapara Yuga will end, there will be a period of 200 years which will be counted in Dwapara and then another 300 years which will be counted in Treta.

Comment: @AnilKumar Likewise, there are sandhi periods in Sri Yukteswar's theory. He wrote the book "The Holy Science" on the request of Mahavatar Babaji which now you also believe as an incarnation of Shiva. So, Shiva himself wanted Sri Yukteswar to write all this. Shiva wanted us to know the correct theory. With all the facts as well as Shiva supporting this theory, I would definitely accept Sri Yukteswar's theory.

Comment: Well to address the original question, there are sharabhas mentioned in the scriptures. Sharabhas are basically reptilian carnivorous birds (or if phrased differently) dragons (or) dinosaurs. @Keshav So is there any specific time period of Sharabhas or anything?

Comment: @Surya As far as I know, Sharabhas are considered as animals living in the "present day" by all scriptures that mention them. There are lots of scriptures that have prohibitions on eating Sharabha meat, for instance.  So I'm pretty sure Sharabhaas aren't dinosaurs. It's more likes Western stories of knights slaying dragons, in that Sharabhas are supposed to be living on Earth side by side with human society. Perhaps it's only in the Kali Yuga that Sharabhas aren't on Earth; just as Gandharvas used to rule forests in India but not anymore, perhaps Sharabhas either left Earth or were all killed.

Comment: @Keshav Or are they just hidden XD

Comment: @Surya Yeah, I suppose that's possible, both in the Gandharva case and in the Sharabha case.  I once went to the India-Tibet border (or India-China border if you prefer) and saw the mountain path the Pandavas died on.  Nearby there was the ancient path to Alakapuri, the city of Kubera.  Apparently nowadays if you walk along that path you get cut off by a glacier fairly soon.  So perhaps the Yakshas are still living in Alakapuri but it's inaccessible to humans.

Comment: @Pandya how is the question Scientific. It is just asking about dinosaurs

Comment: @AnuragSingh Dinosaurs  are not discussed in scriptures, it would be scientific speculation I think.

Comment: @AnuragSingh IMO, this is off-topic not because of 'scientific speculation' but because it's about dinosaurs and not Hinduism. I can frame many such questions which appear to be on-topic but they really aren't. (E.g., To which yuga does Anurag Singh belong? In which yuga did the Wright brothers make the first manned, controlled & powered flight? In which yuga did the first single-celled organisms appear on Earth?) Now a question like 'In which yuga was Swami Vivekananda born?' maybe on-topic, but that's just a silly way of asking 'Which yuga are we currently living in?'

Comment: @sv. Okay. I understand. Thanks for explanation.