# Sahadeva's knowledge of future

Tags: mahabharata, pandavas, sahadeva

Sahadeva, after eating a part of his father Pandu's brain, got the power to see the past and the future.

So he came to know that these things will happen:

1. Game of dice
2. Draupadi's insult
3. Kurukshetra war

Considering the outrage of modesty of a woman that too his wife, couldn't Sahadeva have blurted out the truth? (He needn't have revealed the 1<sup>st</sup>  and the 3<sup>rd</sup> things)

Now that it was fate if he had revealed the happenings he would have died, couldn't he have sacrificed himself at least to protect his wife's modesty?

Why didn't he do so?

Comment: Eating brain of a human being that too father, is this even allowed in hinduism??

Comment: You can check the content of this here: https://www.quora.com/What-parva-of-the-Mahabharata-contains-the-story-of-Sahadeva-where-he-eats-his-fathers-brain

Comment: It was all pre-planned  leela of God. Krishna knew all this would happen. Without that incident would Mahabharatha war have happened? After war Dharma was established by killing Kauravas. IMO, evil or bad should happen to see or experience Good. Like to experience cold you have to feel heat, one has to experience bad in order to experience good. That's reason why Dharma degrades with ages. It's cycle. When bad reaches its peak, Good comes from it. You can see from this how evil people changed to good and virtuous. http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/9205/3500

Comment: @AnilKumar, thanks for your answer :) let me wait for few more.

Comment: @AishvaryaKarthik Your question is based on the fact that Sahdev has eaten part of the body of Pandu and thereby he knows about the future but that incident is not described in Mahabharata. It finds place in some Telegu folklores based on Mahabharata. This is described in this answer: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/5455/1018

Comment: Though Sahadeva can see the future, if he tells them about it, he'll die as it will be going against fate.

Comment: I never heard Sahadev ate part of his dad’s brain 