# Could Sahadeva predict the future?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, history, siddhi, sahadeva

I read this on a forum:

> Sahadeva could predict the future, but he was also cursed to die if he revealed it to anyone. He didn't reveal the outcome of the war to Krishna.

Also, [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9310/sahadevas-knowledge-of-future) question says that Sahadeva could do this because he 'ate part of Pandu's brain'!

I would like to know the original story from the *Mahabharata*.

Comment: Cool , agreed on this one, its duplicate