# Did Sahadeva have the knowledge of past, present and the future?

Tags: mahabharata, sahadeva

I want to know if sources like the Mahabharata, translated by KM Ganguli or the critical Edition of the Mahabharata translated by Bibek Debroy, say that Sahadeva knew the past, present and future.

I'm not asking if Sahadeva ate Pandu's body to get his wisdom. I am asking if that supposed wisdom of Sahadeva is in canonical texts like KMG or BORI

Comment: Similar question already exists here. We can answer that question from critical edition also. - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11910/could-sahadeva-predict-the-future

Comment: How is this question a duplicate to that question?

Comment: It is exact duplicate of [Could Sahadeva predict the future?] (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11910/5212). But that question is also closed as duplicate. The answer is there is no mention of Sahadeva having such knowledge of future or past in Mahabharata. The answer says it. Hence it is a duplicate.

Comment: t is true, but if it is closed as a duplicate for something that I have already clarified that I am not asking, then there is no need to duplicate my question