# If Sahadev was a big astrologer who knew the results of the war before hand why couldn't he save his sons?

Tags: mahabharata, pandavas, kurukshetra, chandravansh, sahadeva

If Sahadev was a big astrologer who knew the results of war before hand why couldn't he save his sons and may be his brother's son ?

Please don't tell me Krishna cursed him not to reveal.

He can't reveal it but why he couldn't save his sons alone being a Kshatriya warrior

Comment: *"why he couldn't save his sons alone being a Kshatriya warrior"* - you answered your own question. A real Kshatriya will not save 'his sons alone' while letting his other fighters/sons die

Comment: Can you tell the reference for Sahadeva being an astrologer?

Comment: @LazyLubber, Sahadeva is the one who fixed the astrological date for Durga puja when Duryodhana asked him. Krishna later changed the Amavasya day itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Pandu's last wish, not to burn his body but eat it away, real?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3518/is-pandus-last-wish-not-to-burn-his-body-but-eat-it-away-real). Actually, it is an exact duplicate of [Sahadeva's knowledge of future](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9310/5212) but it's closed as a dupe of question I linked.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma could you tell from which vansh / Kul did Raja Drupad , Madri and Shakuni belonged to ?