# How will the Kalki avatar look like?

Tags: vishnu, avatars, kalki

How will the **Kalki** avatar look like, appearance-wise? I have heard he'll have a sword and ride atop a horse. Is it true?

Comment: may be kalki will look like this: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=kalki&espv=2&biw=1360&bih=643&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAWoVChMIlvCH1KmAyAIV0QuOCh2fng9K  :) :) :)

Comment: It is not possible. Muhammad is not kalki. They are stupid not to know that Kalki is avatar of Lord Vishnu.

Comment: @BhavinPatel You should give "Kalki avatar" and not just "Kalki" to avoid similar named actress. :) Some Muslims say that prophet Muhammad was the Kalki Avatara. I also heard that in 1 of the Zakir Naik's lecture where he compared few similarities. In today's time I don't think this avatar will come on horse.

Comment: @iammilind If kalki avatar had born hindus would worship him. :D :D :D, so muhammad is not kalki avatar. muhammad is off topic on this site. :P

Comment: @iammilind - you are right i should have search "kalki avtar",  compare this in reverse of zakir naik see my answer here: https://www.quora.com/Why-cant-anybody-expose-the-contradictions-in-lectures-of-Dr-Zakir-Naik/answer/Bhavin-Chhatrola

Comment: @iammilind - in today's time will not possible they will come on Horse with sword but they will come after 427000 (aprox.) years , and we have enargy like gas ,oil ,coal till 2000 to 5000 years than there no cars , bike may be see this 1,172,348,265,480 Oil left (barrels),13,957 Days to the end of oil (~38 years),1,128,259,895,479 Gas left (boe),59,382  Days to the end of gas, 4,365,996,931,277 Coal left (boe) : see in enargy section http://www.worldometers.info/ In future human do not have this facility like cars bike etc...so may be kalki avtar come on Horse ..

Comment: @BhavinPatel, though I get what you are saying and agree to certain extent, but that Yuga theory is not correct. According to some people all the Yugas are in lacs of year starting from Krita Yuga the highest, then Treta, then Dwapara and then Kali. That is just a speculation. e.g. According to Yukteshwar Giri (the Guru of Paramahamsa Yogananda), we are back in Dwapara Yuga which he mentioned in his book [The Holy Science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Holy_Science#Passages_from_The_Holy_Science.5B1.5D). In this book he debunks the theory of Kali = 432000 years. I found him more logical.

Comment: @iammilind "According to some people all the Yugas are in lacs of year starting from Krita Yuga the highest, then Treta, then Dwapara and then Kali. That is just a speculation." It's not speculation at all, it's straight from the Vishnu Purana: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/5253/36 Now you may believe that it's not true, but it's not accurate to call it speculation.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan, according to Jaggi Vasudev, the "amount of time" is different for different consciousness. May be it's possible that the author of Purana might have written something and people might have miscalculated it to an overwhelming number. If Dwapara finished just 5k years back and modern human evolved 50k-100k years back then how can we explain the remaining years of Dwapara? I don't say that Vishnu Purana is wrong but it's possible to misinterpret. Yukteswar Giri's theory of all yugas in 24k year is more logical, where he takes basis of Sun. It impies that Kalki already happened.

Comment: @iammilind There's no need to worry about whether people have misinterpreted it in the past; just read it for yourself and see whether any other interpretation is even possible: "Thirty Muhúrttas constitute a day and night of mortals: thirty such days make a month, divided into two half-months: six months form an Ayana ... and two Ayanas compose a year. The southern Ayana is a night, and the northern a day of the gods. Twelve thousand divine years, each composed of (three hundred and sixty) such days, constitute the period of the four Yugas, or ages."
http://sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp037.htm

Comment: @iammilind Yeah that's the question - if Kalki happened then who was he!   The last Kali Yuga ended in 1699 and the only one who took incarnation around that time was Shiva as I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2220/what-is-the-duration-timeline-of-the-four-yugas/9965#9965).

Comment: @iammilind Shivaji rode on horse with sword in his hand, he was probably the closest in resemblance to Kalki as mentioned in the scriptures but Kalki is supposed to kill a lot of evil from earth. Shivaji did a lot but may not be on the scale of Kalki.

Comment: In Kali Yuga, Rakshasas (Kali or evil) resides in Heart and they don't have any specific body. That's the reason Kali Yuga has many philosophers (such as Adi Shankara, Swami Vivekananda etc) than other Yugas. **HORSE** represents knowledge and it was Hayagriva Avatar of Vishnu that recovered Vedas. **NANADAKA** also represents **Gnana** which was incarnated as famous saint **ANNAMACHARYA**. So, Lord will be great philosopher. Lord Kalki (remover of filth) removes Kali (evil) from hearts of people with help of KNOWLEDGE. (1/2)

Comment: According to some saints, Lord Kalki was born in Shambala city in deep Himalayan Ranges. He will come to limelight after 2025, which is beginning of transition period of Kaliyuga and Satya Yuga. (2/2)

Comment: @ParthTrivedi Accept the answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Lord Kalki will receive a horse, a sword and and an all knowing parrot (Suka) from Lord Shiva. His physical appearance is described by his wife Padmavati, Demi Gods and others too.**. This is described very nicely in Kalki Purana...

Lord Kalki after his sacred thread ceremony goes to Lord Parashuram to attain trainings in military arts. It is in chapter 3 of Kalki Purana:

> Text 7 
>   *daksinam prarthaya vibho 
>
>   ya deya tava sanmdhau 
>
>   yayd me sarva siddhhsyad 
>
>   ya syat tvattosa kdnni*
>
> Lord Kalki said: О my Lord, please tell me what kind of daksina I 
>   should give You so that You will be pleased, > and I will thus be able to 
>   achieve complete perfection in life.
>
> Text 8 
>   *rama uvaca 
>
>   brahmana prdrthito bhumana 
>
>   kali nigraha karanat
>
>   visnuh sarvasrayah pumah 
>
>   sa jdtah sambhale bhavan*
>
> **Parasurama said: О great soul! Long ago, Brahma prayed to Lord 
>
>   Visnu, the shelter of all living entities and the Supreme Personality of 
>
>   Godhead, to destroy the influence of Kali. I understand that You are that 
>
>   same Supreme Personality, appearing in the village of Sambhala.**
>
> Text 9 
>   *matto vidyam swadastiam 
>
>   labdhva vedamayam sukam 
>
>   simhale ca priyam padmam 
>
>   dharman samsthdpayisyasi*
>
> You have learned the art of discharging arrows from Me. **You will 
>
>   imbibe transcendental knowledge from Sukadeva Gosvami, and You will 
>
>   be awarded a powerful weapon by Lord Siva. Thereafter, You will marry 
>
>   a woman named Padma from the island of Simhala. Your mission is to re 
>
>   establish sanatana-dharma.**

Then by following the words of Lord Parashurama, Lord Kalki does penance of Lord Shiva and finally praises with hymns. Those hymns will be very popular in next Satya yuga. It is also in chapter 3 :

> Text 21 
>   *iti kalkistavam srutia 
>
>   suvah sarvatma darsanah 
>
>   saksdt prdha isannisah 
>
>   parvati sahito'gratah*
>
> After hearing these prayers, Lord Siva, being omniscient, appeared 
>   before Lord Kalki with Parvati and spoke to Him while smiling grandly.
>
> Text 22 
>   *kalkeh samsprsya hastena 
>
>   samasta vayavam muda 
>
>   tamdha varaya prestha 
>
>   varam yatte'bhi kdmksitam*
>
> Lord Siva caressed the entire body of Lord Kalki with his hands and 
>   then said: О foremost of all beings, please ask from me the benediction 
>   You desire.
>
> Text 23 
>   *waya krtamidam. stotram 
>
>   ye pathanti jana bhuvi 
>
>   tesdm sarvartha siddhhsya 
>
>   adiha loke paratra ca*
>
> Anyone on this earth who faithfully hears the glorious prayers that 
>   you have offered me will achieve all kinds of > perfection, both in this life 
>   and in the next.
>
> Text 24 
>   *vidydrthim capnuydd vidydm 
>
>   dharmdrthim dharmam apruyat 
>
>   kamdn avapnuyat kdnx' 
>
>   pathanat srvanddapi*
>
> If a student recites these prayers, his education will become fruitful, 
>   if a pious person recites these prayers, he will attain pious merit, and 
>   if a sense enjoyer recites these prayers, he will enjoy all kinds of sense 
>   gratification. Anyone who recites or hears  these prayers will have all his 
>   desires fulfilled.
>
> Text 25 
>   *warn garudam ida casvam 
>
>   kamagam bahurnpnvxm 
>
>   sukamenanca sarvajfiam 
>
>   maya dattam grhana bhoh*
>
> **This horse was manifested from Garuda, and it can go anywhere at 
>
>   will and assume many different forms. Here > also is a parrot that knows everything—past, present, and future. I would like to offer You both the 
>
>   horse and the parrot and so please accept them.**
>
> Text 26 
>   *sanasastrastra vidvamsam 
>
>   sanavedartha paragam 
>
>   jayinam sarvabhutanam 
>
>   warn vadisyanti manavah*
>
> **By the influence of this horse and parrot, the people of the world will 
>
>   know You as a learned scholar of all scriptures who is a master of the art 
>
>   of releasing arrows, and thus the conqueror > of all.**
>
> Text 27 
>   *ratnat sarum kardlanca 
>
>   karavala mahaprabham 
>
>   grhana gurubharayah 
>
>   prthwya bhdra sadhanam*
>
> **I would also like to present You this sharp,  strong sword and so please 
>
>   accept it. The handle of this sword is bedecked with jewels, and it is 
>
>   extremely powerful. As such, this sword will help You to reduce the heavy 
>
>   burden of the earth.**
>
> Text 28 
>   *m vaca dsrutya 
>
>   namaskratya mahesvaram 
>
>   sambhala grama gamat 
>
>   turagena tvararwitah*
>
> After hearing all this, Lord Kalki offered His obeisances and then 
>   departed for the village of Sambhala, riding on the back of the horse 
>   given by Lord Siva.
>
> Text 29 
>   *pitaram mataram bhratan 
>
>   namaskrtya yathavidhi 
>
>   sarvam tadvarnayd masa 
>
>   jamadagnyasya bhasitam*
>
> Upon arriving home, Lord Kalki offered his respectful obeisances 
>   to His father, mother, and brothers. He then narrated whatever had 
>   happened and told them about the orders of His guru, Paras'urama.

Then that all knowing parrot goes to island of Simhala and tells about Lord Kalki to Padmavati. When Padmavati see Lord Kalki she describes Lord Kalki as (in chapter 9):

> Text 20 
>   *sukhe bауапаt mamvedika gatam 
>
>   kalkim purastad atisurya varcasam 
>
>   mahamani biаса vibhusana atam 
>
>   sukena sarddham tamudaiksa tesam*
>
> There, Padmavati saw her beloved Lord Kalki peacefully sleeping on 
>   a raised platform that was decorated with jewels **The effulgence of His 
>
>   body defeated the brilliance of the sun His entire body was decorated 
>
>   with varieties of precious jewels.**
>
> Texts 21 
>   *tamala nilam kamalapatim prabhum 
>
>   pitambaram caru saroja locanam 
>
>   ajanu bahum prthupina laksasam 
>
>   sri vatsasat kaustubha kantirajitam*
>
> **The complexion of the Lord of Laksmi was dark, like a tamala tree, 
>
>   and He was dressed in yellow garments He had lotus-like eyes, His arms 
>
>   reached to His knees, and His chest was  very broad and displayed the 
>
>   mark of Srivatsa and Kaustubha gem**
>
> Texts 22-23 
>   *tadadbhutam rupam aveksya padma 
>
>   samstambhita usmrta satknartha 
>
>   suptam tu sambodhayitum pranttam 
>
>   nibarayamasa usankita sa 
>
>   kadati eso nah talo tirupi 
>
>   maddarsanat stritiam upaiti saksat 
>
>   tadatra kim me bhanta bhaiasva 
>
>   i arena sapa piatimena lole*
>
> Upon seeing the transcendental form of the Lord, Padmavati became 
>   stunned and fearful Indeed, she became so overwhelmed with emotion 
>   that she forgot to greet her Lord When Suka attempted to awaken the 
>   Lord, she forbade him, saying If this greatly attractive hero looks at 
>   me and is transformed into a woman, then what will be the use of the 
>   benediction that I had received from Lord Siva.
>  Truthfully, I consider 
>   Lord Siva's benediction to be a curse. [[Padmavati was formerly blessed by Lord Shiva that whoever would see her through lust he will immediately turn into women]]

Lord Kalki's physical apperance is also briefly described in chapter 10, Marriage of Lord Kalki and Padmavati..

> *Text 19 
>
>   padmakalki gaurakrsnau 
>
>   vipantantard bubhau 
>
>   bahihsphutau mla pita 
>
>   vasovyajena pasyatu*
>
> **Padmavati's complexion was very fair and Lord Kalki's complexion 
>
>   was dark, like a rain cloud. In this way, they appeared to materialistic 
>
>   vision to be opposite one another. Princess > Padmavati was dressed in blue 
>
>   garments, and Lord Kalki was dressed in yellow garments.**

Also in the chapter 33 demigods appear to earth and praise Lord Kalki as::

> The Demigods Arrive at Sambhala 
>   The Disappearance of Lord Kalki
>
> Text 1 
>   *suta uvaca 
>
>   tato devagandh sarve 
>
>   brahmand sahitd rathaih 
>
>   svaih svair ganaih parivrtak 
>
>   kalkirh drastm updyayuh*
>
> Suta GosvamI said: Once, all the demigods and great brahmanas, 
>   along with their followers, mounted their celestial chariots and went to 
>   the village of Sambhala, to see Lord Kalki.
>
> Text 2 
>   *maharsyah sagandharvdh 
>
>   kinnards capsarogandh 
>
>   samdjgmuh pramuditdh 
>
>   sarhbhalarh surapujitam*
>
> Many exalted sages, Gandharvas, Kinnaras, and Apsaras cheerfully 
>   arrived at Sambhala, which was highly desired even by the demigods.
>
> Text 3 
>   *tatra gawd sabhd madhye 
>
>   kalkirh kamalahcanam 
>
>   tejonirhdhim prapanndndrh 
>
>   jandndm abhayapradam*
>
> As they entered the palace courtyard, they saw the greatly effulgent 
>   lotus-eyed Lord Kalki giving assurances to all those who had come to take 
>   shelter of Him.
>
> Text 4 
>   *rala jimutasarhkdsarh 
>
>   digha pivara bhdhukam 
>
>   kintendrka varnena 
>
>   sthiravidyun nibhena tarn*
>
> ***His transcendental body was the color of a dark rain cloud. His 
>
>   arms were long and very powerful. His head > was adorned with a brightly 
>
>   shining crown that resembled the sun.***
>
> Text 5 
>   *sobhamanarh dyu manina 
>
>   kundalondbhi sdbhina 
>
>   saharsdldpa vikasad 
>
>   vadanam smita sobhitam*
>
> **The beauty of His face was enhanced by His earrings, which were as 
>
>   brilliant as the sun. His lotus-like face appeared to blossom as He sweetly 
>
>   smiled while speaking.**
>
> Texts 6-7 
>   *krpakataksa viksepa 
>
>   pariksiptavi paksakam 
>
>   tara hdrollasad vaksas 
>
>   candrakdnta mamsriyd 
>
>   kumudvatl modavaharh 
>
>   sphurat sakrdyudhdmvaram 
>
>   sarvaddnanda sandoha 
>
>   rasollasita vigraham*
>
> **Everyone surrounding Him was favored by His merciful glance. Lotus 
>
>   flowers adorning His chest appeared more delightful because of the rays 
>
>   of the moonstone that shone in His beautiful necklace. His garments 
>
>   appeared like a rainbow, thus further increasing his beauty.**
>
> Text 8 
>   *ndndmaniganodyota 
>
>   dipitarh rupam adbhutam 
>
>   dadrsur deva gandharvdm 
>
>   ye cdnye samupdgatdh*
>
> **His entire body shone brilliantly due to the light reflected from 
>
>   countless jewels. This is how all the demigods, Gandharvas, and Apsaras 
>
>   saw Lord Kalki.**

Comment: So the events described in Kalki Purana have happened already or yet to take place?

Comment: @sv. They are yet to take place... They will take place after this Kaliyuga...

Comment: Your first blockquote says "Lord Kalki said..." so obviously it's referring to the past. So is the Purana talking about a past Maha-yuga?

Comment: @sv. It is a common practice of describing a future event in past tense in our scripture... It is so because when sages want to know about future,... by samadhi they go to future and become third person omnipresent at that place and of that event... so for them it is already happened... so they describe by past tense like "said", "went", etc...

Comment: Well, re: Kalki, Sage Markandeya in MB [talks](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03189.htm) in future tense and Sage Parashara in VP also [talks](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp117.htm) in future tense.

Comment: @sv. The cases you have given above aren't in the state of being third person omnipresent in future... It is just telling future by vision... furthermore KalkiPuran tells it is going to be in future in many places... for eg...

Comment: @sv. Text 8
suta uvdca
srnudhvam idam dkhyanam
bhavisyam paramadbhutam
kathitam brahmand purvam
ndradaya viprcchate
Suta GosvamI said: Please listen attentively as I describe wonderful
pastimes of the Lord **that will be revealed at a future time.** These
transcendental pastimes were previously glorified by Lord Brahma, who
was born from the universal lotus flower, when he was> requested to speak
by the great sage, Narada