# Are we in Kali-Yuga's pre-Sandhi period?

Tags: yuga, kali-yuga, time

The time-cycle of creation is that each Chatur-Yuga is 43,20,000 years, split up as such:

1 deva day = 1 human year.
1 deva year = 360 deva days.
1 deva year =  360 human years.

Each Yuga is calculated in certain number of deva years plus a tenth of it before and after called sandhis.

kali yuga = 1200 deva years = 100 pre-sandhi + 1000 + 100 post-sandhi

dwapara = 2 x Kali = 2400 deva years = 200 pre-sandhi + 2000 + 200 post-sandhi

treta = 3 x Kali = 3600 deva years = 300 pre-sandhi + 3000 + 300 post-sandhi

krita = 4 x Kali = 4800 deva years = 400 pre-sandhi + 4000 + 400 post-sandhi

So does that mean that when Sri Krishna left earth, the post-sandhi period of Dwarapa Yuga (200 deva years or 72000 manava years) got completed, and now we are in the pre-sandhi period of Kali Yuga (100 deva years or 36000 manava years)?

100 deva years = 36,000 human years. Of which we are currently (2018) in year 5120.

Does that mean Kali-Yuga 'main' (after pre-sandhi period is over) doesn't start until 31000 years from now?

Note - Some people assume that these numbers (1000, 2000 etc.) are in human years, but they're not.

Comment: Brahma Purana - 
Text 50

sri-bhagavan uvaca
kaleh pancasahasrani
varshani tishtha bhutale
papani papino yani
tubhyam dasyanti snanatah

Translation:

The blessed Lord said: On the earth 5,000 years of kali will be sinful and sinners will deposit their sins in you by bathing.
kaler dasha-sahasrani
madbhaktah santi bhu-tale
ekavarna bhavishyanti
madbhakteshu gateshu ca

Translation:

For 10,000 years of kali such devotees of mine will fill the whole planet. After the departure of My devotees there will only be one varna [outcaste].

Comment: Seeing this convo of supreme Lord and mother Ganga in Brahma Purana, you could be right. By the way from where did you get this information?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which Yuga are we currently in? Numbers don't add up](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10688/which-yuga-are-we-currently-in-numbers-dont-add-up)

Comment: @YDS, not duplicate. that question wrongly assumes the years mentioned (4800, 1200 etc.) are human-years.

Comment: Yes we are in sandhi period of Kali yuga now.

Comment: is it a question or an answer?

Comment: Yes according bannaje the sanndhi period is 36000 odd years as you have stated, that is where statement like there is no avatara of vishnu in Kali yuga can hold true, otherwise we have buddha and kalki.. avatara in kali yuga which makes the statement false and contridictory

Comment: @PrasannaR - where does it say 'no avatar of Vishnu in Kali Yuga' ? Also, just because we are in Sandhi period, doesn't mean it's not kali yuga. it's like 5.30-6.30 am is called sandhi or dawn or morning time, but it's still part of that day.

Comment:  If we are in Sandhi what will happen in actual Kaliyuga???? Also please change your name to ram again it’s really weird seeing this mar. I initially respected you merely seeing your name before we interacted.

Comment: @Archit - i don't deserve to keep that name :(

Comment: @Archit - we are in Kali Yuga. It's just that the initial few years is called Sandhi because it is closely associated with previous yuga. When we do Sankalpa in rituals, we say 'Kali Yuge' only, not 'Kali Yuga Sandhye'

Comment: Okay :(. Yes yes the sankalpa. I feel technically the ending of dwaparayug was associated with Kali more than our sandhi with dwaparayug.

Comment: @Archit - i think you're confusing the terms. Imagine if the last hour of the english day (11pm to midnight) , and first hour (midnight to 1 am) was called as 'wee hours'. Does it mean 'wee-hours' are not part of that day ? It's just a name for it. So, ending of dwapar yug, which happened in 3102 BC is the same time as beginning of kali yug.

Comment:  nice explanation. What I meant was 11 pm to midnight had more effects of Kaliyuga (though it was part of Dwaparayug)

Comment: @Archit - you only say that because you've seen what happens in the end 11.55 to 12pm. But you've only seen the first 5 minutes from 12-12:05. Once you see 12.55-1am, you'll realize how bad Kali can get.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, [Time Period of Lord Brahma](https://photos.app.goo.gl/XqeTmX8TbpMdjRfJ8)In Every Time Period. There are some points which is noticed

1. There is **Post Sandhi** we call it **Sandhi**  Starting of Every { Yuga }.

Then

2. There is Time Spaning Period Which are called Divine Years,etc.

Then

3. There is **Pre Sandhi** we call it **Sandhyaansh** Ending of Every { Yuga }.

**Back to Your Question**

Are we in Kali Yuga Sandhi Period. Not in Proper Kali Yuga Yet?

Yes, If you read deep the [**(First Part of 3rd Chapter, Shri Vishnu Purana)**](https://photos.app.goo.gl/mvP2PtQsPa2hNebH7)In this chapter you will get your clear anwer.

And Thanks for Q'r that this was raised. Everyone will see that.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, Kali-yuga comprises of only 1000 divya years excluding 200 years of transition period. We are specifically in pre-sandhi period of Kali-yuga according to Jyotiṣa Vedāṅga [Ref. Sūrya Siddhānta Chapter 1.17] which would be the most appropriate place to look at for this question. Another reference of the same is in Mahābhārata, 12.231,

> The duration of the Kali yuga is one thousand years, and its morning extends for one hundred years, and its evening for one hundred.

P.S: Not just Yuga Sandhi, there are Kalpa, Manu, etc. Sandhi-s as well.