# What scriptures discuss Krishna's time in relation to the Yuga Sandhi periods?

Tags: krishna, yuga, kali-yuga, time

It is commonly said that Krishna departed the Earth in 3102 BC and the Mahabharata war occurred in 3138 BC, a little over five thousand years ago.  But I just found indication these events may have happened much earlier.  In [this document](https://vdocuments.mx/qa-velkudi-krishnan.html), the Sri Vaishnava lecturer U. Ve. Velukkudi Krishnan Swami says this:

> Dvaparayuga consists of 864000 years out of which 720000 years is the actual yuga and 72000 years of purva sandhi and 72000 years of uttara sandhi. Sri Krishna departed this material world on the last year of the actual yuga i.e. 720000th year. Mudal azhvargal were born after Sri Krishna during uttara sandhi kalam.... This confusion would arise if we assume that Krishna departed on last day of dvapara uttara sandhi. But in fact He departed on the last day of the actual dvapara yuga.

Let me explain what he's saying.  There are four Yugas: Satya, Treta, Dwapara, and Kali.  Now 
 Dwapara Yuga and the Kali Yuga are often described as 864,000 years long and 432,000 years long respectively, but strictly speaking the actual Dwapara Yuga and actual Kali Yuga are 720,000 years long and 360,000 years long respectively.  But each Yuga has two Sandhi Kalas or transition periods on either side, which are one tenth the size of their respective Yugas, as described in [this chapter](http://sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp037.htm) of the Vishnu Purana:

> Thirty Muhúrttas constitute a day and night of mortals: thirty such days make a month, divided into two half-months: six months form an Ayana (the period of the sun's progress north or south of the ecliptic): and two Ayanas compose a year. The southern Ayana is a night, and the northern a day of the gods. Twelve thousand divine years, each composed of (three hundred and sixty) such days, constitute the period of the four Yugas, or ages. They are thus distributed: the Krita age has four thousand divine years; the Tretá three thousand; the Dwápara two thousand; and the Kali age one thousand: so those acquainted with antiquity have declared. The period that precedes a Yuga is called a Sandhyá, and it is of as many hundred years as there are thousands in the Yuga: and the period that follows a Yuga, termed the Sandhyánsa, is of similar duration.

So what Velukkudi Krishnan Swamy is saying is that Krishna departed the Earth on the last day of the actual Dwapara Yuga.  We, on the other hand, are living five thousand years after the start of the actual Kali Yuga.  So that would mean that between Krishna departing the Earth and our time is the 72,000-year Uttara Sandhi period of Dwapara Yuga, plus the 36,000-year Purva Sandhi period of the Kali Yuga, plus the 5,000-odd years that have elapsed in the actual Kali Yuga thus far.  So that would imply that Krishna departed the Earth 113,000 years ago, not 5,000 years ago as is commonly believed.

My question is, do any scriptures describe when exactly Krishna departed the Earth in relation to the Uttara Sandhi period of the Dwapara Yuga and the Purva Sandhi period of the Kali Yuga?  Did he depart the Earth at the end of the actual Dwapara Yuga, or at the end of the Uttara Sandhi period of the Dwapara Yuga, or the end of the Purva Sandhi period of the Kali Yuga, or what?

Comment: Related question - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/28711/we-are-in-kali-yuga-sandhi-period-not-proper-kali-yuga-yet .. Why do you feel that we are living in proper Kali Yuga, and not in Kali-Yuga sandhi ?

Comment: I saw a [article](https://m.livehindustan.com/live-blog/janmashtami-celebration-live-update-in-mathura-at-sri-krishna-birthplace-temple-and-iskcon-temples-across-the-country-2706854.html) today (Janmashtami) that Krishna was born in 8,63,874th Dwapara year..that means post sandhi period of Dwapara...

Comment: Krishna is later than Rig Veda And Rig Veda cannot be much older than 1400 bc - the date of the firmly dateable Mitanni inscriptions with Indo-Aryan words.  So Mahabharata, which knows the Veda must be younger.  A good date is around 300 - 400 bc, by using the  firmly dateable Greek invasions.

Comment: Not really the list of Indo-Aryan words given by PE Dumont are not found in the old parts of the Rig Veda.

Sadly River Sarasvati exists and no it is not an Afghani river Hemland, Hemland was never even known to be Sarasvati, it was some tributary of it which was called Sarasvati

Answer (score 4):

In Shanti Parva, Sri Krishna blessed Bhishma with the knowledge of the past, present, and the future and Bhishma tells Yudhisthira how Vishnu in the beginning of the world told Narada about the avatars he will take and this post mentions about Krishna's birth and purpose.

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12c039.htm

> **Towards the close of the Dwapara and beginning of the Kali ages, I shall again appear in the world taking birth in the city of Mathura for the purpose of slaying Kansa.** There, after slaying innumerable Danavas that will be thorns in the side of the deities, I shall take up my residence in Kusasthali at the city of Dwaraka. While residing in that city I shall slay the Asura Naraka, the son of 'the Earth,--him, that is, who will do an injury to Aditi, as also some 'other Danavas of the names of Muru and Pitha.

Mahabharata discusses how Krishna would be born during the intervals of Dwapara and Kali ages.

Answer (score 2):

The below verse says Kali yuga started immediately after Krishna departed.And we know that Krishna appeared in Dwapara yuga and lived for 125 years. So he departed at the end of Uttara Sandhi of Dwapara yuga.

> SB 12.2.33: Those who scientifically understand the past declare that
>   on the very day that Lord Śrī Kṛṣṇa departed for the spiritual world,
>   the influence of the Age of Kali began.

Comment: it only said about influence of age kali not about kaliyga starting kali yuga started when Duryodhana left, Sri Krishna lived 30 yrs in kali yuga that why we are saying krishnarpnamasthu after doing karma.. because he is closely related avatara in Kali yug otherwise we have to tell vedavyasa arpnamasthu or budha arpanamasthu or ramaarpnamasuthu @RaRe

Comment: @PrasannaR You should post an answer if you have scriptural basis for what you are saying.

Comment: All it says is "the influence of the Age of Kali began".  The Sandhikalas are transition periods between Yugas, so the influence of the Kali Yuga might have started entering the world in the Uttara Sandhi period of the Dwapara Yuga.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan One more reason why I think Krishna departed not in actual Dwapara is that Kali gained full strength after 1150 years of Pariksit. If we don't think Krishna departed at the end of uttara Sandhi, Kali got full strength in Dwapara itself which should be odd. SB 12.2.32: When the great sages of the Saptarṣi constellation pass from Maghā to Pūrvāsāḍhā, Kali will have his full strength, beginning from King Nanda and his dynasty.SB 12.2.26: From your birth up to the coronation of King Nanda, 1,150 years will pass.

Answer (score 2):

Srimad Bhagavatam 1.4.14 translates as this:

> Suta  said: Vyasa was born    in  the womb    of  Satyavati   as  a   portion of  the Lord    when    the third part  of  Dvapara-yuga    arrived in  the passing of  yugas.

This third part of Yuga is explained by Srila Vishwanath Chakarvarti Thakur as follows

> All   yugas   are divided into    three   parts:  the
>   beginning   portion (sandhya-rupa), the middle  portion (yuga-rupa) and the end
>   portion (sandhyamsa-rupa).  Trtiye  refers  to  the third   part    of  Dvapara-yuga.2  *
>   (The    proportions are .1  for the beginning   portion,    .8  for the middle  portion and .
>   1   for the concluding  portion of  the yuga.)

As we know that Vyasadev was  contemporary of Lord Krishna so lord Krishna's pastime took place in the Sandhamsa of Dwapara yuga (Uttara sandhi) not the middle portion. Therefore, His pastimes ended and brough the Kali Yuga. Therefore we won't count the Uttara Sandhi. 
Now question arises whether we are now in the middle portion of Kali Yuga or the purva sandhi of kali Yuga, I am not sure.