# Do Yugas change every 12 years or so?

Tags: yuga, time

I know about 4 yugas and their timelines which runs for lakhs of years.

But in childhood I heard from people that after every 12 years or so Yuga changes. Is it a different type of Yuga ? Where this thing is written ?

Comment: Vyazhavattom. 12 years is the revolutional period of Jupiter, i.e. the amount of time it takes for Jupiter to complete one revolution around the sun. This is called a 'vyazhavattom' in Tamil and Malayalam.

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11779/661

Comment: @hanugm - Kali Yug started in 3102 BC according to all Panchang used today which is based on Surya Siddhant. By your link's logic, kali yug finished in 2102 BC. so now we are living in Krita Yu ? Nonsense

Comment: @mar My intention is to share the Mahabharata answer from the post.

Comment: @hanugm - and that answer is wrong, because it includes noted atheist sv (aka Say No To Censorship)'s personal opinions.