# Who is Soma Natha?

Tags: shiva, identification-request, guru

For Kaliyuga, Lord Shiva has appointed 12 great gurus each for 500 years. Which will keep repeating till the arrival of Satyuga.

> 213. Therefore, henceforward twelve Great Souls shall uphold My Law upon Earth. Their noble
>        names which are forever established among the Stars are: **Duravasa, Dharmakunda, Satyapati,
>        Mahakala, Adinatha (Vrishabhanatha), Ramanatha (the Buddha's Guru), Jaleshvara, Svacchanda,
>        Shambhunatha, Guptanatha, Soma-Natha, and Siddhanatha**. They are Rays of My Own Light.
>        Shining from the Land of Glory they illumine the World. Verily, for five hundred years each
>        they shall proclaim My Word in this World and beyond. Thus six thousand years shall pass; and
>        when they have passed away, twelve more Masters shall descend into the World. When seventy-
>        two such cycles (of 6,000 years each) have passed, I Myself shall return to Earth, but not before.

Source: Shiva Rahasya Purana Chapter 11

Current great Guru is Soma Nath but I am unable to get any information about him as this is 5112th year of Kaliyuga. Can anyone find something about him, any information from scriptures?

---

Note that:

- These names might be the name of the post.
- Among them ShambhunAth was the Guru of great Kashmiri Shaiva AchArya Abhinavgupta, whereas Ramnath was Ramputra, one of the Guru of Gautam Buddha.

Comment: _"this is 5112th year of Kaliyuga"_ So you mean 888 years of kaliyuga has left?(asking for curiosity)

Comment: @Rishabh No, the traditional length of the Kali Yuga is 432,000 years; see my answer here: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/5253/36 What the quote is saying is that the 432,000 years of the Kali Yuga are divided into 72 periods of 6000 years each, and that during each 6000-year period 12 gurus are born.  The Kali Yuga started in 3102 BC, so we would be living in the first 6000-year period.

Comment: You have now started asking the so called Story Qs- What is the story of Somanatha? :D

Comment: @Rickross Actually, I am curious to know who is that master. :)