# Is Shiva Rahasya book authentic?

Tags: scripture, shiva, identification-request

A year ago I had found a very interesting book on Lord Shiva's teachings named as Shri Shiv Rahasya (You can read [here](https://archive.org/details/ShriShivaRahasya)) which I thought inauthentic mere by looking at it. But after reading it just for sake of intellectual itching I found it coherent with other scriptures mainly Agamas, like it is talking about **36** tattvas, deriving from Durvasa or Triyambaka, describing various yogic teachings, yam, niyam etc (for the reasons I have answered from this book in many answers). In fact, I didn't find any single contradiction there. Also, at the end the book claims how the teachings in it came from Lord Shiva as follows -

> 81. The Supreme Lord Himself revealed this Teaching to the Holy Sages, Duravasa, 
>       Nageshanatha, Kapalin and Anandanatha.
> 82. Sage Duravasa Who Dwells Afar imparted it to his disciples, Tryambakanatha, 
>       Amardakanatha and Shrinatha, and these transmitted it to their disciples. I myself heard it from 
>       these and I have spoken it to you. Do you now impart this Greatest of Teachings to others that 
>       the Command of the Lord may be brought to pass.
> 83. Thus spoke Venerable Sage and God-Seer Vyasa, the worshipful son of Great Yogi 
>       Parashara and Charming Satyavati. May Shiva's Grace and Peace be eternally upon them all! ?
> 84. Here ends the Secret of Shiva spoken in verses twelve hundred and thirty. Over the 
>       centuries, Shiva's Eternal Teaching had become corrupt. Deprived of His Guiding Light, the 
>       World could no more tell Truth from Untruth. Yogi Soma-Natha, the humble devotee of Lord 
>       Shiva, like a dutiful gardener at the command of his Master, after enquiring into the Truth, has 
>       mended and set in order the course of the great stream of Spiritual Instruction known to the wise 
>       as Shri Shiva Rahasya (The Glorious Mystery Of Supreme Reality), that it may nourish the 
>       Divine World Garden through which it majestically flows, causing it to flourish and bear fruit for 
>       the welfare of all. May the Lord be pleased with my work and may it by His Grace bring Peace 
>       upon Earth! May all Souls be happy! Obeisance to the Supreme. OM.

Now consider **84th** verse it seems the book is of recent creation, maybe of **21st** century, although teachings are ancient. The compiler of the teachings (Like Veda Vyas is compiler of Vedas) is said to be Somnath which I discuss in [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21759/who-is-soma-nath) question. Somnath is a divine secret Guru of current world sent by Lord Shiva to propagate spirituality. (at least what the book claims).

So, I want to know whether any scholar talked about the book? Or is the book available in Sanskrit? Is there any more information about the book - like of publisher, introduction, preface etc? Or Is the book an Agama with different name? Do any scripture mentions that Lord Shiva gave instructions at the arrival of Kaliyuga as the book claim? Or are there sufficient evidences to prove the book an inauthentic one?

Answer (score 8):

Yes it is authentic. Because it has all the commentary of Acharya Somananda from Kashmir Shaivism. Let's see what wikipedia says about his lineage:

> There is considerable myth surrounding the origins of Somananda. He claimed he was a descendent of the sage Durvasa. Durvasa received from Shiva the spiritual mission of keeping the tradition and secrets of Agamic Shaivism alive. It is said that Durvasa created his son, Tryambaka, directly from the mind (in a similar way with the creation of Athena directly from the mind of her father, Zeus, in the Greek mythology). In turn, Tryambaka also created a son directly from his mind. This went on for 15 generation terminating with the father of Sangamaditya, who took a woman as a wife. Then, there were three more generations until Somananda.[4][5] So, Somananda claims a divine spiritual ancestry and investiture.

Wikipedia Reference Link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somananda

Acharya Somananda was also considered to be disciple of Vasugupta whom Lord Shiva himself reveal the Shiva-Sutra.

Acharya Utpaldeva was non other than but son of Acharya Somananda himself whose philosophy is well adopted now as Kashmiri Shaivism.

So, considering what mentioned above, we can assume, the book is authentic.

Comment: Wrong answer.  :), Somanath and Somananda are different...

Answer (score 4):

Yeah Shiva Rahasya Itihāsa's auntencity is beyond any Doubt. It is one of the Itihasas and one of the Major and important scripture of Shaivism.

- **There's a clear mention of Śiva Rahasya Mahētihāsa in Liṅga Purāṇa, Pūrvabhāga, Chapter 26,
  Verse 28.**

  > **अष्टादशपुराणानां ब्रह्माद्यानां तथैव च।। तथा चोपपुराणानां सौरादीनां यथाक्रमम्।। २६.२७ ।। पुण्यानामितिहासानां शैवादीनां तथैव च।।
  > श्रोत्रे
  > स्पृशेद्धि तुष्ट्यर्थं हृद्देश्यं तु ततः स्पृशेत्।। २६.२८ ।।**
  >
  > **~ Liṅga Purāṇa,1.26.28**
  >
  > For the propitiation of eighteen Purāņas beginning with Brahma, for
  > the propitiation of hteen Upapurāņas beginning with Saura, and for
  > the propitiation of **holy Itihāsas beginning with Śaiva(Śiva Rahasya**
  > **Mahētihāsa).**

---

And there's a **commentary on Śiva Rahasya Itihāsa by Shri
Somananda** too. Here is the link

> https://archive.org/details/ShriShivaRahasya/page/n1/mode/2up

---

And The **Ribhu Gita (dialogue between Ribhu and Nidagha)** which
comes under Śiva Rahasya Mahētihāsa is mentioned and quoted by
Smartha and Shaiva Acharyas.

> **The dialogues between Ribhu and Nidagha on the Supreme Brahman(Parāśiva) also**
> **appear in** Tejobindu Upanishad of Krishna Yajurveda, Mahopanishad of
> Sama Veda, Annapoornopanishad of Atharva Veda and Varahopanishad of
> Krishna Yajurveda.

---

> Śivatoṣiṇī (शिवतोषिणी) is the name of a Ṭīkā (commentary) on the
> Liṅgapurāṇa.—The author of Śivatoṣiṇī is Gaṇeśa Nātu—the son of
> Ballāla and Yaśodā and the disciple of Nīlakaṇṭha.
> In Śivatoṣiṇī, Śiva Rahasya Itihāsa is mentioned.

---

> Also the very famous and Great **Commentary on Shri Rudram by Bhagvān
> Kārttikeya** himself is present in Śiva Rahasya Mahētihāsa itself.

Answer (score 3):

The Shiva rahasyam Purana is authentic and the manuscript are found in tanjore library. This is a ithihasa which has all the conditions and right to become itihasa. This is a part of conversation between jaigishavya and skanda bhagwan. It is very very old.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism SE! Can you provide for the claim that it is  authentic and have all rights to be considered an itihasa?

Comment: It contains the Ribhu Geeta and General Version of Rudrashtadhyayi which may be chanted by everybody regardless of their initiation into the Vedic tradition. The purana is authentic but the English book to which the OP has referred to may not be strictly accurate and it is definitely incomplete.