# What is the story of the "Shaiva Itihasa" or Shiva Rahasya Itihasa?

Tags: shiva, puranas, shaivism, itihasa

The Shaiva Linga Mahapurana mentions the Shaiva Itihasa in [Chapter 1.26](https://archive.org/details/LingaPuranaJ.L.ShastriPart1/page/n109/mode/2up?view=theater&q=itihasas)

> For the propitiation of eighteen Puranas beginning with Brahma, for the propitiation of eighteen Upapuranas beginning with Saura, and for the propitiation of **holy Itihasas beginning with Saiva,** he shall touch his ears and the cardiac region. (Verses 26-28)

This Shiva Rahasya Itihasa is supposed to comprise of approximately [100,000 verses and it was published in entire 30 volumes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shivarahasya_Purana). **So it is about the same size as Mahabharata!!**

Can anyone tell the outline of the story, or part of the story, in brief or very short way? Like who are the main characters, what happened etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which is the Shaiva Itihasa that Linga Purana is talking about?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/30173/which-is-the-shaiva-itihasa-that-linga-purana-is-talking-about)

Comment: No definitely not @YDS I am asking for story