# What is the real Hindu chronology?

Tags: mahabharata, puranas, history

Some people say that span of  Sat Yug , Treta Yug , Dwapar Yug and Kali Yug are 17.28 Lakh  , 12.96 Lakh , 8.64 Lakh and 4.32 Lakh years respectively.

But recently I have gone though some books and articles on the internet in which different chronology of Hinduism is presented.

Like -  In this book - https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B0846WKRQM/
Satyug is shown to start at 14500 BC , Treta Yug at 6777 BC , Dwapar Yug at 5577 BC and Kali Yug at 3176  BC.

There are multiple such claims by other people as well .
Here are some other links that also give similar timelines as above of Hindu history.

http://veda.wikidot.com/hindu-timeline (Satyug starts at 7000 BC)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3tsyzrDg2n4 (Satyug Starts at 15000 BC)

What is the real timeline ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How many days are there in one Yuga?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/5252/how-many-days-are-there-in-one-yuga)

Comment: @Archit So, All those books and articles written are false ? Those people have written the book based on astronomical evidence in books such as Mahabharat , Ramayan and Puranas . Plus they have also used other evidences like drying up of Sarswati river etc. 

The timeline written in Purans can be wrong as we all know the original texts written by Ved Vyas is lost and the current texts are not accurate.

Comment: Also please don't close this question so quick . I know about timelines written in Bhagvada Purana. But there are many books in Hinduism . Plus I want to know what is the take on books written by those people ?

Comment: 1. Timelines in Puranas are correct 2. Astronomical events can repeat . If something happened in 15000 BC , it could very well have taken place earlier at 150000 BC or 15 million years ago. 3. All books that propose non Puranic timelines in a way are saying Puranic events didn't take place. There are events other than Ramayana and Mahabharata