# Will there be a day when lord brahma stops creating us?

Tags: brahma

All of us are aware that brahma is the creator of every living being. But,

- Was there or will there be a situation when he will be taking a break from this?
- Doesn't he have any vacations?
- How long will he be creating?

Comment: Check this link out: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/5482/age-of-brahma-1-day-of-brahma-and-science.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the process of creation will cease upon the annihilation of the universe.

> Bhagavad Gita 8.17–19:
>
> (17) By human calculation, a thousand ages taken together is the duration of Brahma's one day. And such also is the duration of his night. (18) When Brahma's day is manifest, this multitude of living entities comes into being, and at the arrival of Brahma's night they are all annihilated. (19) Again and again the day comes, and this host of beings is active; and again the night falls, O Partha, and they are helplessly dissolved.

As the Bhagavad Gita explains, the universe is annihilated and created cyclically. Upon the annihilation of the universe, Brahma himself ceases to exist, since Brahma is a created being whom Vishnu created. The Bhagavata Purana explains:

> Bhagavata Purana 1.3.1–3:
>
> (1) Sûta said: "In the beginning the Supreme Lord assumed, for the creation of the worlds, the form of the Original Person[: the integrity of the material realm] composed of the sixteen elements [of the ten knowing and working senses, the mind and the five elements] and the cosmic intelligence and such. (2) Resting in His meditative slumber in that water, out of the lotus that spread from the lake of His navel, Brahmâ was manifested, the master of the progenitors in the universe. (3) One believes the different worlds [as expansions] to be part of the form of the Fortunate One that constitutes the excellence of the purest existence.

When Vishnu inaugurated the universe, He created Brahma to continue the process of creation to ensure the "self-sufficiency" of the universe without involving Himself. Brahma continues to create. The Bhagavata Purana later explains:

> Bhagavata Purana 12.4.1–7:
>
> (1) S'rî S'uka said: 'Time beginning with the smallest of the atom and culminating in the two halves [or parârdhas] of the life of Brahmâ, o King has been described [in 3.11] together with the duration of the yugas; now listen to the annihilation of the kalpa. (2) A thousand cycles of four yugas is said to be a kalpa, a day of Brahmâ, in which there are fourteen original progenitors of mankind [Manus]. (3) When they are done there is the dissolution described as the night of Brahmâ that is of the same duration; the three worlds remain dissolved till the end of that time. (4) This is said to be the occasional annihilation [or naimittika pralaya] in which [Nârâyana] the creator of the universe lies down upon His bed Ananta, to absorb the universe including Lord Brahmâ. (5) After the completion of two parârdhas [viz. the two half life times] of the highest situated living being, Lord Brahmâ, are the seven elements [mahat, ahamkâra and the tanmâtras], subject to destruction. (6) This, o King, constitutes the elemental annihilation. Therafter this universal egg, this aggregate [of these seven universal principles] reaching the time of its disruption, will dissolve.

As long as it is the day of Brahma, the universe continues to exist. When it becomes the night of Brahma, the world is annihilated and remains in its dissolved state as long as it is the night of Brahma. The Bhagavata Purana explains (as one can see above) that the night of Brahma is of the same duration as the day of Brahma. Therefore, there is a time at which Brahma will not be creating, and that time is during the dissolution of the universe, which lasts for as long as the universe exists. After this period of dissolution, the universe will again become manifest, as per scripture.

At the end of the life of Brahma (100 years of Brahma), he will die. The period of his death will last as long as his life. The cycles of the universe (the life of Brahma) will then begin again.

Comment: Brahma is not destroyed during Pralayas.  Only Devaloka, Bhuloka, and Asuraloka are destroyed during the Pralaya - other Lokas remain intact.  The Pralaya just constitutes a night for Brahma, during which he goes to sleep.  After the Pralaya is over, Brahma wakes up and creates the three worlds again.  Brahma only dies during Mahapralayas.  A Kalpa is one day in the life of Brahma.  A Mahakalpa is 100 years in the life of Brahma.  It's only at the end of the Mahakalpa that Brahma dies and the Mahapralaya, of equal length to the Mahakalpa, begins.

Comment: My answer here discusses all this: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2876/36

Comment: The life of Brahma doesn't consist of 100 days, it consists of 100 years.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by 'us'? I am the Atman. Brahma creates bodies, he does not create atmans. If you identify yourself with your body, then a body you will remain. "He who considers himself free is free indeed, he who considers himself bound remains bound. This popular saying is true: As one thinks so you become." Astavakra Samhita (I. 11.)

Understand that Brhama is a jiva who has the 'post' of Brahma for 1 cycle. After a cycle ends, there is a period of rest. After that a new cycle starts with a new Brahma (a new jiva).

Comment: I also heard there there is no life long brahma, its somthing like post that is given to particular jiv.

Comment: I also read in one book(I forgot name of book) that Aswasthma (from Mahabharat) will become one of Sapt Rushi when next new world will create by brahma. Is this type of cycle is true?

Comment: @Kiran Sorry don't understand your question.....maybe make it a little clearer....

Comment: Sorry for not clearing, What you said is Brahma is jiv who has 'post' as Brahma for this one cycle. Is that means, in next cycle there will be other jiv who come as 'post' of Brahma?