# Which Pralaya is the final destruction of the Universe(big crunch)?

Tags: pralaya

In the Dharmic belief system, Pralaya is used in the context of natural cataclysms on the earthly plane that bring about the end of one Mahayuga and the beginning of next one. But is there a specific name for the Pralaya that brings about the end of the all creation(Shristi) that is equivalent of the Big Crunch? According to the puranas, What will be the event or events that triggers this final pralaya and who/what exists beyond the final pralaya? What are the timescales involved?

Comment: See my answer here, which details the different kinds of destruction: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2876/36 The biggest destruction is the Mahapralaya, coming at the end of a Mahakalpa.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan, I don't think this is a duplicate of the linked question/answer. Some parts of that answer may apply to this question but that doesn't make this a duplicate of the other question: [What exactly happens at end of Kali Yuga. How will the world be destroyed?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2875/2995) (which is only about Kali Yuga and its end, and not the end of all creation)