# Why the names of yugas are satya, treta, dwapara and kali?

Tags: scripture, yuga

I want to know what are the meanings of yugas' names.

Why are they called  satya , treta , dwapara and kali ? Are there any reasons for such names of the yugas ?

What do our scriptures say about the names of yugas ?

And also I want to know that if the yuga's name is satya yuga 
then why the asura and rakhshsa like (Hiranyakashipu and Hiranyaksha) existed in satya yuga
,so why its call satya yuga ?

Comment: It's based on the names of Vedic dice rolls, as I discuss here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7545/36 In any case, the Yugas have to do whether humans are good or evil, it doesn't preclude the existence of other evil beings.

Comment: Nice @keshav got it.

Comment: 1) A word is a "sabda" to denote something.
2) Satya = whole truth, truth is on four legs Treta = tre = three, truth is in three legs Dwapara = Dwa = Second, truth is on two legs Kali = Truth is on single leg
3) As the wheel of time changes, the yuga cycle also changes.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I [think](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8029/why-the-name-of-yuga-is-satya-treta-dwapara-and-kali#comment16921_8029) you should post an answer.

Answer (score 6):

- **Sathya** means truth. During that age, truth and perfection prevails. So it is called as Sathya Yuga.
- **Treta** means collection of three things. As three Avatars happened in Treta Yuga, it is called so.
- **Dwapara** means two pair, two ahead or after two, which symbolize two yugas already gone and two is there.
- **Kali** - In Kali Yuga represents Kali Purusha, as he is a demon who is the reason for degraded people and religious practices.

Comment: This is a good answer. Also, I read in a Pancha-Anga that in Satya 4/4 parts is truth, in Treta 3(tri)/4 parts is truth, in Dwaapara 2(Dwa)/4 parts is truth, and in Kali 1 out of 4 parts is truth.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What are the three avatars in Treta yuga ?