# Who is Kali Purusa ? Where did he come from ? How could he reign over a complete yuga of 4,32,000 years?

Tags: kali-yuga, kali

It is known from SB that Kali Purusa has come as soon as lord krishna departed the earth.
As soon as he came he was beating the holy cow.
After he was defeated by maharaja parikshit he begged for his presence in some places where there wealth, gambling, intoxication etc.
But where did he come from suddenly?

why couldn't he affect the people of other ages ?

How could he influence the minds of the people in this complete yuga?

Why there is interference of Gods in the affairs of humans directly in this yuga?

It is also said that all the demi-gods left the earth before the beginning of kali yuga else they lose their powers.

How kali can be so powerful?

He cannot be unknown as he is one of the creation of the supreme. At the end of this yuga he will be eliminated by the supreme himself.

Why this creation and elimination of kali?

Comment: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/6699/3500 . This answer explains how he was born. According to Hinduism, both good and evil was created by Brahman and he doesn't recognize good or bad but everything goes according to karma. http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/6796/3500 This explains it. I was partially satisfied with those philosophical answers. Even i asked related question . you can see here https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8262/who-are-satya-treta-dwapara-and-kali?

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8029/why-the-name-of-yuga-is-satya-treta-dwapara-and-kali?  You can see comment section of this question

Comment: Kali what I know to my best knowledge is son of lord Bramha and why this creation and destruction? you cannot ask this question regarding kali purusha because you are also part of same cycles.

Comment: He didn't come all of the sudden.He was present in previous kaliyuga. In 19th kaliyuga of Vaivastha manu (current Manu) Parushurama killed all evil kshatriyas on this earth. Currently we are in 28th kaliyuga. According to wiki page, unlike other demons kali cannot be killed and he escapes to kaliyuga of next chaturyuga.

Comment: @AnilKumar From did he come all of a sudden in this age? Lord brahma might had created him at the time of creation itself.
how couldn't he affect the people of other ages?
how could he reign over a complete yuga or a yuga completely attributed to him to have his evil forces to work in ?

Comment: @AnilKumar according to kalki purana, after being defeated by lord kalki , kali dies from wounds of dharma and satya personified. He is not immortal . He should die some how.

Comment: Don't take the magic figure of 432000 too seriouly. It's just a cooked up theory to show some superlativeness. Apply simple logic, if Dwapara finished 5000 years back and humans evolved 100000 years back then where are the remaining years of Dwapara? There is a question asked few days back here only about archeology findings of Rama's existence just 7000 years back. Which appears more logical. According to Yukteshwara Giri, all yugas are within span of 24000 years. Currently we are in Dwapara in reverse cycle.

Comment: @iammilind It's not a cooked up theory, it's stated in the Vishnu Purana.  In any case, Yukteswar doesn't even believe in the existence of Manvantaras and Kalpas.  His views are flatly contradicted by Hindu scripture.

Comment: @iammilind lost city in the gulf of cambay mention it is 9000 years old http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/south_asia/1768109.stm 
The archaeological survey by GSI states that ram setu might have formed 18,000 years ago with the technology they had in 2007 http://www.frontline.in/static/html/fl2419/stories/20071005500500400.ht m. These dates keep on revising with the advent of new technology and new evidences.  According to latest evidences modern humans evolved around 2,00,000 years ago http://anthro.palomar.edu/homo2/mod_homo_4.htm.

Comment: @iammilind as per the latest accounts early humans were present before 2.6 million years ago. http://humanorigins.si.edu/human-characteristics/tools-food. These may extend further if new fossils are found. There is nothing concrete on the theories based on archaeological findings they keep on improvising with new evidences and technology

Comment: Kiran, It's widely accepted that, Modern human evolved 50k-100k years back and its predecessors 'Homo X's are found 400k years back based on fossil. Let's assume Rama setu 20k years back. Considering Dwapara of so called 800k+ years, we are still half way :). @KeshavSrinivasan, just found that wiki article suggests that early texts of Manu were indeed referring all Yugas in 24k years. But that's not my basis. Vishnu Purana may be right about Yuga ratio but there can be issue with the multiplier used to convert to human years. Otherwise difficult to explain my above comment of Dwapara duration.

Comment: Acceptance changes with new fossil evidences and with the technology the time scale changes. When i was in school i read humans evolved around 10,000 years ago but today it has become ten times. Our scriptures are interpreted widely by many scholars, we cannot come to a concrete conclusion that this is the particular date.  According to astrology it was in the year 5114 BC the appearance of lord rama. But acc to the Bhagavata Purana, Vayu Purana and valmiki ramayana some evidences say that it might had happened 18 MYA. Refer the site http://www.stephen-knapp.com/lord_rama_fact_or_fiction.htm

Comment: @Iammilind  Yukteshwar has many valid points, however his math is theoretical because a precession cycle take approx 27000 years.  Yuga as a concept  works at all time scales. There is a 1 day, 1month, 1,5,60,27000 year yuga. Bheeshma when asked by Yudhistar explains by saying that the actions of a king decides the Yuga. Wherever Maya is at its peak, you can be sure that Kali is operating. However there are many places and people unaffected (like Yukteshwar!) by Kali. If everyone realises that their actions decide the Yuga, we will stop having such discussions.

Answer (score 2):

I was hearing the discourse on Bhagwat purana by Sri Chaganti VR (in telugu) and what I came to know is that after the great war of Mahabharata, the only heir left of Pandavas was Parikshit ( Abhimanyu's son), apart from Pandavas' themselves. After ruling for sometime, Pandavas make Parikshit the king and leave the kingdom. After some time, Pandavas leave their mortal bodies and also does Lord Shri Krishna. King Parikshit is very righteous and becomes a great king who adheres to DHARMA all the time. This is towards the end of Dwapara yuga and the beginning of the Kali yuga. Kali cannot exist where there is dharma and a king like Parikshit who is a dharmatma. Arrival of Kali yuga marks the beginning of the kali yuga. Kali purusha existed before too but because of the dharma, he could not set his foot on the earth. 
Please note that this is only my understanding of the events.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism. Though you attempted to answer the question, this doesn't answer completely Op's question. Please edit the answer by adding more info and citing sources. Please visit [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/125/3500)