# Is Kali yuga the last yuga of the world?

Tags: vishnu, kalki

Is our Kali Yuga is the last yuga of the world? Please somebody answer my question!

Comment: No, there are many more yugas to come. World will get destroyed at the end of Kalpa(Brahma's day).

Comment: No, we're living in the 28th Mahayuga of the Vaivasvata Manvantara, which has 71 Mahayugas, and the Vaivasvata Manvantara is the seventh Manvantara of the Shwetsvaraha Kalpa, which has 14 Manvantaras.  The world will only be destroyed at the end of the Kalpa; see my answer here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2876/36

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Doesn't Yukteswar reject the notion of Kalpas?

Comment: @Goltu You've posted so many questions and answers, why don't you register your account?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan No he doesn't.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Well, perhaps you know Yukteswar's system better than I do.  What does he believe about the length of a Kalpa, then?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan He didn't mention about Kalpas and Manvantars which led you to believe that he rejected those. There is a difference between not mentioning and rejecting. The book he wrote "The Holy Science" was not a book to explain yuga theory but it was written for surfacing the unity of messages of Hinduism and Christianity. All he wanted to tell people is that the current age is Dwapara.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan But his disciple, Paramahansa Yogananda did mention the age of Brahma. He says a day of creation is 4,300,560,000 years which is identical but not same to the traditional number which is 4,320,000,000 years. Similarly, Yogananda gives 314,159,000,000,000 years the the Life of Brahma, whereas traditionally the number is slightly different: 311,040,000,000,000 years.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Yogananda's number for the Life of Brahma is a multiple of pi, the length of the solar year, and Yogananda's number for a Day of Creation. Thus the Life of Brahma (314,159,000,000,000 years) divided by a Day of Creation (4,300,560,000 years) = 73050.72, which divided by 2 is 36525.36, which in turn is more or less a multiple of the number of days in a solar year (365.25).

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan This vast figure given by the rishis is based on a relationship between the length of the solar year and a multiple of Pi (3.1416).

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan This was the figure given by our ancient rishis but unfortunately, certain scholars got it completely wrong. They decided to add one single word "divine" and multiplied traditional yugas with 360 years which messed up the whole theory and that's how we arrive at the wrong calculation.