# How will we know the end of first part of the Kali yuga?

Tags: rituals, yuga

As we know, There are four yugas (Satya, Treta, Dwapara, Kali). Every yuga consists of four parts (known as pādā  in sanskrit). Many are aware that in the daily rituals we perform, we say ***Kali yuge prathama pāde*** as a part of Sankalpa of that pooja. It is quite common in almost every pooja.

My questions:

- If this sankalpa continues for generation after generation, how will it change even if we enter the second pāda of kali yuga?
- How will we know that the first part of the yuga is completed? Will there be any indication?
- Is time period of kaliyuga equally divided among four parts?
- Does the adharma get more prevalent in the next parts of this yuga?

<sup>The above question is not a duplicate of [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2875/what-exactly-happens-at-end-of-kali-yuga-how-will-the-world-be-destroyed) question.</sup>

Comment: Good question.  One thing is that the Brahma Vaivarta Purana says that the first 10,000 years of the Kali Yuga will be a golden age, and that the Ganga river will dry up after the first 5000 years of the Kali Yuga.  But many consider that passage to be an interpolation, and in any case it's already been more than 5000 years and the Ganga river is still here.  And I'm not sure if any of this has to do with a change in Pada.

Comment: [Yugas are divided in the ratio 4:3:2:1](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34611075#34611075)

Comment: @Pandya 4:3:2:1 is the ratio of the lengths of the four Yugas.  But I don't know of any scripture that says that the Padas of a given Yuga are in the ratio 4:3:2:1.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Ganga will dry after 5000 years according to Brahma Vaivarta Purana? Which verse says so?

Answer (score 13):

Nothing very definitive but some indications are given in the [Bhavisya Purana](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/bhavishya/bookview.php?chapnum=31):

> Then Bali and Kalki Devi approached Narayana in the form of Vamana who
>   in turn enabled a Brahmana called Kama Sharma and his wife Devahuti on
>   the banks of Yamuna River; he blessed that this couple would give
>   birth to Bhoga Simha and Keli Simha. These two sons would stay in a
>   Kreedavati Nagar and would carry out the wishes of Kali Yuga Devi,
>   especially in the task of wide-spread Varna-sankara or destroying the
>   Rules of Varnashrama.
>
> Over two thousand years, the established Regulations made by Lord
>   Brahma and **the successive Manus would get thinner and thinner and by
>   the Second Paada of Kali Yuga, Kali Devata would be happy to witness
>   that the old Vedic values would be obliterated, that the Daityamaya
>   human beings (fully soaked in Daitya activities) would be of
>   two-and-half feet height, that their life span would be forty years
>   maximum (as against hundred years now) and that they would be free
>   like birds without any Karmic regulations!**

What happens even after that ? i.e in the last remaining quarters of Kali Yuga are also given in the same chapter:

> **At the end of the Kali's second half** there would **neither by the
>   institutions of marriages, nor Kingships, nor any social reformer and
>   not even a Karma Karta! The World would be full of the progeny of
>   Bhogi Simha and Keli Simha** and this kind of a situation devoid of
>   customs and social norms woud prevail for one and quarter lakh years!!
>   **In the Third Quarter of Kali Yuga, the average age of human beings
>   would be twenty six years maximum;They would be too lustful and
>   produce too many children and resort to affairs with co-males and
>   animals!.......** In the **fourth phase of Kali Yuga the maximum age of
>   humans would not exceed tewnty years and live like water-beasts and
>   animals;** hells like Tamistra and worse kinds of frightening Places of
>   Retribution would be over-populated

So.basically, when we find human beings  are having **heights of around two and a half feet** and when their **life span on average is not more than 40 years** we can assume that the first pada of Kali is over.

Comment: Do you know anything about 1st and 3rd questions?

Comment: @SreeCharan I think one can't continue using the same sankalpa in the 2nd pada ..It has to change accordingly..As regards ur 3rd Q i am not quite sure..

Comment: Because in your answer you stated " this kind of a situation devoid of customs and social norms woud prevail for one and quarter lakh years". So I think they are divided like that.

Comment: @SreeCharan Yes i too think so but i'm not sure..

Comment: Good informations... rarely found. Thanks

Comment: No problem Mr Polai. @KailashChandraPolai

Comment: @Rickross could you please let us know the year like 3019 when 1st part of kali yuga will end? And how can we believe blindly whatever our ancester wrote? Come on they didnt know any complex maths then like its now.

Comment: No I don't know any year like that .. we can verify many of the things they wrote as true .. that's how gradually belief grows ..  @PratikCJoshi also having faith in Gods and scriptures is considered a good trait in Hinduism ..

Comment: @Rickross having faith and trusting blindly are different things

Comment: Yes but most people do not trust blindly .. they are always in look out of some sort of proofs/verifications .. because for humans direct perception is the highest proof @PratikCJoshi so u can not keep blindly believing in a concept for a long time without getting subjective proofs from time to time about it's validity

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of pādā is different. As per Surya Siddhanta (chapter 1, Verse 15 - 19), a pādā ("dharmapādā" to be precise) is a fixed time period corresponding to 1200 divine years (year of the devas). Kali Yuga has a single pādā; Dwapara yuga has two pādā; Treta yuga has three pādā and Krtha yuga as four pādā. Hence saying "kali yuge prathama padhe" is correct but the pādā reference is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

**Only when a dharmic king is ruling the earth not when any Kalki arrives.**

Following is the text from Bori CE Mahabharat's Udyoga Parva:

> If a lord imposes chastisement on the four varnas in accordance with the dharma that they should follow, that ensures that they do not transgress dharma. If **a king follows chastisement properly and completely**, this signifies the commencement of the best era, **known as krita yuga**. You should have no doubts about whether the era creates the king, or **the king creates the era**. It is the **king who creates the era**. The king is the creator of krita yuga, treta and dvapara. The king is also the cause of the fourth yuga. If a king is the cause of krita, he enjoys heaven for eternity. If a king is the cause of treta, he enjoys heaven, but not for eternity. By leading to the commencement of the dvapara, a king obtains an appropriate share of those fruits. An evil-acting one dwells in hell for an eternity. The earth is touched by a king's taints and also he is touched by the earth.

**Author of the above text:** Bibek Debroy who translated sanskrit text to English.

Comment: Could you quote that image part as text too?

Comment: As TheLittleNaruto has mentioned in his comment, please quote the text instead of adding a screenshot. We discourage "screenshot only" answers. You can add emphasis using [Formatting help](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/formatting). Please add @ before user name so that the user who commendted can get back to you. Anyways, this is my question - How can we make a call that the Kalki is going to arrive or an era is starting? Who makes the call? Also can you elaborate what you mean a dharmic king is ruling? We will know a part is ending? Please [edit].

Comment: it seems like a "editor" already quoted it