# Who are the śaka purushas?

Tags: yuga, kali-yuga, calendar, panchang

In my [recent question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16653/how-will-we-know-the-end-of-first-part-of-the-kali-yuga), I asked about the pādas of the yuga. This time my question is about  śakas (era). Many of you are aware that we live in the śālivāhana śaka era. Even though the current year according to Gregorian calendar is 2017, the present year in śālivāhana śaka is 1939.

Now my questions are:

- Who are the śaka puruṣā for the current yuga?
- On what basis is a śaka started?
- How are these persons identified? Should they have performed great deeds to qualify?

Comment: Kalki is not said to be from Kolhapur. It is said He will appear in Sambhal (Moradabad district of UP). There is a Kalki temple there right now, and a regular Kalki festival every year.

Answer (score 5):

This is the answer of your first question only

According To [**Date Panchanga**](http://www.datepanchang.com/Free_Services/Panchang.aspx) (Hard Copy) which is in Marathi language.
There are **six Shaka-Kartas  in Kaliyuga**-:

> 1) **Yudhishthira (Dharmaraja)** - Indraprastha -His Saka (Time) was of
>   **3044**  years.
>  2) **King  Vikaram** - Ujjain (
>   Madhya Pradesh) - His saka (Time) was of **135** years.
>  3) **King
>   Shalivahan** - Paithan (Maharashtra)- His saka (Time) was of **18,000**
>   years.

---

**Future sakas** -:

> > 4) 
> >     **King VijayaBhinandan** - Near banks of Vaitarni River -His saka will be of **10,000** years.
> > 5) **Nagarjuna** - In Gauda desha ( Gauda
> >     country) His saka(Time) will be of **400,000** (Four Hundred
> >     Thousand) years.
> > 6)**Lord kalki** - In Kolhapur region -His saka
> >     (time) will be of **821** years.